# Kotlin interface implementation "explicitly"

Tags: kotlin

I have two interfaces with same signature method but return type different. Interfaces look like as below,

```
interface IIntCalculation {
    fun Add(a:Int, b:Int): Int
}

interface IDoubleCalculation {
    fun Add(a:Int, b:Int): Double
}
```

When I try to implement those interfaces, obviously it'll conflict as same signature and it show the error as **Conflicting overloads: public open fun Add(a: Int, b: Int): Int defined in test.Calculation,public open fun Add(a: Int, b: Int): Double defined in test.Calculation.** Sample code as below,

```
class Calculation : IIntCalculation, IDoubleCalculation {
    override fun Add(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun Add(a: Int, b: Int): Double {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

So, can I implement those interfaces as **explicitly**?

Thanks in advance for any kinds of help and suggestions.

Comment: Impossible as all methods in Kotlin (and Java) are virtual.

Comment: you can try generics, but it's not explicitly for Int or Double. One thing you can do is use only one interface and place both methods there? perhaps change their naming

Comment: It would be cool if delegation could make this work (but it doesn't).

Comment: As Pawel mentioned, it is not going to work. Another option would be to create an anonymous class implementing each interface, then you can access the interface method something like this `Calculation().addInt.add(1,1)`. Not really a good approach though.

Comment: Even if it would be possible, what return type shall this method invokation choose?

Comment: @Lecagy, Invocation will be explicitly. There is approach in C# where you can implement this interfaces.