# How to avoid overload conflicts in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, design-patterns, overloading

Suppose I have these interfaces

```
interface BaseDatabase

interface UpdatingDB {
    fun getSessionStat(): UpdaterSessionStat
}

interface InsertingDB {
    fun getSessionStat(): InserterSessionStat
}
```

And I want a class to implement all of them

```
class MyDB: BaseDatabase, UpdatingDB, InsertingDB {
    override fun getSessionStat(): UpdaterSessionStat {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getSessionStat(): InserterSessionStat {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

But it results in overloading error. What are probable fixes\workarounds here to be able to have one class implemented all those interfaces ? With except for modifying interfaces itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748964/kotlin-interface-implementation-explicitly

Comment: Well even if you would be able to do that, how would you specify that you need to call a function that returns that? You can't. Maybe try using generics that may be a choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two methods with the same name and same parameters in one class. As a workaround you can have a constructor with params of interfaces' types:

```
class MyDB(val updatingDB: UpdatingDB, val insertingDB: InsertingDB): BaseDatabase {
    fun getSessionStat1(): UpdaterSessionStat {
        return updatingDB.getSessionStat()
    }
    fun getSessionStat2(): InserterSessionStat {
        return insertingDB.getSessionStat()
    }
}
```

Implement those interfaces in different classes:

```
class UpdatingDBImpl : UpdatingDB {
    override fun getSessionStat(): UpdaterSessionStat {
        // ...
    }
}

class InsertingDBImpl : InsertingDB {
    override fun getSessionStat(): InserterSessionStat {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's never going to be possible. If two methods have the same name and take the same arguments, the compiler is never going to be able to tell which one to call and so can't compile. There is simply no way to decide which instruction to process next. (Inferring by the how the returned value is used not viable because that would sacrifice type safety: what if you really meant the *other* one?)

You might want to look at the [Kotlin spec](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spec/blob/e509383ca18ffe526d0739cde741bb89340b8a2c/docs/src/md/kotlin.core/overload-resolution.md#algorithm-of-msc-selection) which mentions:

> If after these [overload resolution] steps there are still several candidates which are equally applicable for the call, this is an overload ambiguity which must be reported as a compile-time error.

Of course there are countless ways to rewrite the code to avoid this and the best depends on your wider program. At the core of the matter though, when those methods are called you must know which of the methods the caller is expecting, and you must use that information pass the caller an object which implements only the relevant interface.